# Why std::move when type is already of the type T&&

Tags: c++, c++11

I've seen this a few places today in people's answers, say I have the constructor for Foo.

```
Foo(      std::vector<SomeType>&& data) noexcept : data_(std::move(data)) {};
```

Why is the std::move(data) necessary because isn't data already of type std::vector< SomeType>&& ?

std::move appears to me that it simply casts data to std::vector< SomeType>&& again?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move
defines std::move as,

```
static_cast<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&&>(t)
```

So it seems that the std::move again is irrelevant in this case, but I am probably missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In both these cases,

```
void foo(const T& bar); // 1
void foo(T&& bar);      // 2
```

`bar` is actually an `lvalue`. What the `&&` means is that overload `2` would bind to an rvalue, for example in cases such as:

```
foo(Bar());
```

whereas overload `1` would bind here:

```
T bar;
foo(bar);
```

In `2`, you still need to use `std::move` to make `bar` look and behave like an `rvalue` inside of the function.

Comment: I see. I guess this is because a named rvalue reference is still an lvalue. 


This article explains it thoroughly. http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_05.html#no_name
> Things that are declared as rvalue reference can be lvalues or rvalues. The distinguishing criterion is: if it has a name, then it is an lvalue. Otherwise, it is an rvalue.

Comment: @capturesteve Yes, that's it. And `std::move` is mainly a trick to hide the name.